# A probability problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> A club has five members $A,B,C,D$ and $E$. It is required to select a
>   chairman and secretary. Assuming that one member cannot occupy both
>   positions, write the sample space associated with these selections

.

**My input**

In my mind I thought of selecting two from these $5$ people first one as chairman and second one as secretary. $5$ choose $2$ makes it $10$ but order doesn't matter because first one can also b secretary and $2$nd can be chairman. Using permutation makes it $20$ possible pairs. 
$AB,BA,AC,CA....$
Did i think it right ?

Comment: You've got the right answer, but I think you meant to say, "Order *does* matter."

Comment: @saulspatz I meant AB and BA are not same thing. So what do I write here ? Order matters or doesn't matter? I am confused.

Comment: Order matters.  If AB and BA are the same, then order doesn't matter.  (We don't care what order they are listed in.)   By AB and BA are different, so the order in which they are listed matters.

Comment: "AB and BA are *not* the same thing" implies *order matters*.  On the other hand "AB and BA *are the same* thing" implies *order doesn't matter*.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for pointing that out. I am learning these things.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M  =\{A,B,C,D,E\}$, then set of interest $S$ (The probability space) is as follows
$$S = \{(s,c)\in M\times M :s\neq c\}$$